# In elastic search, how to copy data from existing fields to new field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to make my search query more fast by using [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#search-as-few-fields-as-possible](http://Tune%20For%20Search%20Speed).
I was using query_string to search a wildcard in multiple fields. Following is my query -

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*fed*",
            "fields": [
              "first_name",
              "last_name",
              "phone_number",
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But, according to the link, if I add another field(full_name_and_phone_number) and use copy_to for first_name, last_name and phone_number and search for one one field i.e full_name_and_phone_number, it will make the search fast. So I added a new field with following query -

```
PUT users/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "full_name_and_phone_number": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "first_name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "store" : true,
      "copy_to": "full_name_and_phone_number"
    },
    "last_name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "store" : true,
      "copy_to": "full_name_and_phone_number"
    },
    "phone_number" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "store" : true,
      "copy_to": "full_name_and_phone_number"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is - If I update index mapping and add the new field in existing index, How will I copy first_name, last_name and phone_number to full_name_and_phone_number for existing documents.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You need to reindex, but I don't fill that will speed up drastically, you can also take a lot to `wildcard` type, which sound more appropriate to your use-case

Comment: wild cards are slow , n-grams will speed this up as tokens are created at index time rather than runtime